# Controller properties (like $scope.data) are working on page1.html, but not working on page2.html

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I have 1 controller and 2 views. 1st view is supposed to be filled with user. when user filling the data I am storing those values using ng-model in controller(For $scope). After submission of the form, I want to use that data in 2nd page. But I am not getting anything. is there any rule like one controller should be specific to one view. Because when I try to display data on 1st pageI am getting correctly. But when I try the same code onpage2.html I am not getting any value and any error even though page is loaded. I searched a lot on SO. but could not find proper solution. I would be very thankful to U, if anyone of U helps me.Thanks a lot in advance

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.item="";
    $scope.remarks="";
      $scope.divCount=[{}];

    $scope.addDiv=function(){
        $scope.divCount.push({});
    };  
})
```

```html
Page1.html

<html>
    <head>
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body
    <form action="page2.html">    
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                <div ng-repeat="count in divCount"> 
                    Item : <textarea rows="4" cols="50"  ng-model="item"> </textarea> <br><br/>
                    Remarks: <textarea ng-model="remarks"  rows="2" cols="50"></textarea> <br><br/>
                    <div>
                        <button ng-click="addDiv();">Add Another Item</button>   
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>




page2.html

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div> item: {{item}} </div>
             <div> remarks: {{remarks}}</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use one controller in two page use ui-router .
You can see here for more infomation

> https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

But i recommend you dont do that using a single controller for multiple views (pages, as you say) is a very poor design for an angular app

Answer (score 0):

On click of submit button in Page1.html store the required data in a service/factory. Retrieve the data from the service/factory in page2.html

Comment: could you add a short example?